# Regex for new line characters

Tags: regex

How to write a regex to extract characters '\n' from "abc\ndef\\nghi" and not '\\n'

Scenario : 
  In a text-area if the user enters a new line then I have to capture them and process them but if the user enters '\n' as a string then I should not process those strings

Comment: Newline is _backslash_ n: \n - not /n.

Comment: Sry, updated the question

Comment: What regex tool are you using?  Do you want to match literal newlines or actual `\n` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not the newline but the string '\n'

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more what you are trying to do here...

Answer (score 0):

If your language/tool supports lookbehinds, `(?<!\\)\\n` will do the trick.

This describes the literal `\n` string that must not be preceded by the literal `\` character. Backslashes in both instance have to be escaped in order to use their meaning as a literal character.

See it in action on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/j8BcGZ/1).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are searching an ASCII string, like `"abc\ndef\\nghi"` then you could do the following:

```
/\\n/g
```

This will find (all)both newline characters. Or,

```
/\\n/
```

to just find the first.

**Edit:** Updated description to showcase if only looking for 1st capture, and removed redundant capture group per comment.

Comment: OP whishes to find only one of these. Not that it matters, but the capturing group in your regex also seems redundant.

Comment: OP wasn't clear they were only looking for the 1st. Updated with both options. Thanks for pointing out the redundant capturing group; also removed